# MySQL- Create Duplicate Results in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | TextA | 3 |
| EFG | TextB | 1 |
| EFG | TextC | 2 |

How do I write a SELECT statement that will return the # of rows for ColumnA and ColumnB based on the values of ColumnC

Expect results:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | TextA |
| ABC | TextA |
| ABC | TextA |
| EFG | TextB |
| EFG | TextC |
| EFG | TextC |

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  and is there some expected maximum value of column c?

Comment: Maximum value of ColumnC is less than 100, total volume is not huge so performance is not critical

Comment: Version is 8.0.19-commercial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(a, b, c) as (
    select cola, colb, colc - 1 from t
    union all
    select a, b, c - 1 from cte where c > 0
)
select a, b from cte order by a;
```